# Sum of not synchronized pandas DataFrame with NaN = non missing value

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have to DataFrames (or 2 Series), I want to sum up two columns (or Series), they are not syncronized, i.e. the index is different.

```
df=df1['A']+df2['A']
```

The problem is that some values in df are NaN, I would like that the sum for elements with missing values corresponds to df1 or df2 (the one with no missing value). It does not help to post-process missing values using fillna.

I can do this with several steps (e.g. merge, than fillna(0), finally sum) but was curious to know if there is a fast way to do this as it is a case which I am encountering frequency.

Thanks

Comment: you example is right out of the docs: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/basics.html#missing-data-operations-with-fill-values

Comment: @Jeff: I am still struggling in finding a similar approach for join or merge, e.g. I join (left) on the index df1 and df2, the result has values of df2 with no corresponding timestamps (these values are NaN currently) which have been extrapolated using a fill_method, e.g. taking the last known value of df2. Does this exist in one command? (this is another recurring use case)

Comment: look at ``.align``, not really sure what you are trying to do

Comment: @Jeff probably too late to ask but could you please post it as answer? This question shows up as unanswered despite being provided with a pin-point answer.